# How to change format with trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers, format

I have a question about Triggers. So I have a table called
Spelers. There is a column which contains a phone number.
Now every time a new speler gets added to the table the phone number format has to change. For example : 070-237893 -> +31 70 237893.

I have to do this with a trigger.

This is what I've got so far:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER
nummer BEFORE  INSERT  
on spelers
FOR each row
BEGIN  



END //
DELIMITER ;
```

So I don't know how to do this. This is the code I have to change the format

```
select concat(replace(left(telefoon,1),'0','+32 '),substring(replace(telefoon,'-',' '),2,10)) as telefoon
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do the job. InMySQL triggers you access the data being inserted through pseudo table « NEW ». In your use case, all there is to do is change the value of the phone number before it gets inserted.

```
CREATE TRIGGER nummer 
BEFORE INSERT ON spelers
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.telefon IS NOT NULL) THEN
        SET NEW.telefon = 
            concat(replace(left(NEW.telefoon,1),'0','+32 '),substring(replace(NEW.telefoon,'-',' '),2,10));
    END IF
END
```

PS : if telefon is a non nullable field, you may remove the surrounding IF block.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know I have to avoid this type of messages from saying thank you. But you have no idea how much you helped me.